Webstie running Vite & react-route-dom doesn't load assets from the correct URL
I have a vite app running with react-router-dom. I have this issue that if I navitgate to a page it all loads fine however if I copy and paste the url into another window it fails to load some assets.
Example below:
I have a site at mysite.blah I can navigate to a page say mysite.blah/page1, all is good. However if I paste that into a new browser window I get and issue where it fails to load one of my assets.
It is trying to load the asset from mysite.blah/page1/assets/index-eufduf.js when the location is
mysite.blah/assets/index-eufduf.js.
react-router-dom@5.3.3
vite@5.2.8
I have tried setting the base in vite.config.ts to "/" but that didn't change anything. I also tried using BrowserRouter instead of Router but to no avail.


/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import EnvironmentPlugin from 'vite-plugin-environment';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  // depending on your application, base can also be "/"
  base: '',
  plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), eslint(), EnvironmentPlugin('all')],
  server: {
    // this ensures that the browser opens upon server start
    open: true,
    // this sets a default port to 3000
    port: 3000,
  },
  build: {
    target: 'esnext', //browsers can handle the latest ES features
  }
});




What server environment or hosting service are you specifically using? The basic gist is that all requests to the server/hosting service for any page in the app need to return the root index.html file, and each server environment/hosting service has different settings/configurations/etc requirements. FWIW this is a backend issue and not anything you can solve in the front end, so React-Router-DOM is largely irrelevant. Can you [edit] to include a [mcve] of the setup/deployment?

Take a look at this deployment documentation to gather a sense what different settings/configurations are used across different servers/hosting services.

Hi, thanks for responding. Using just vite and serving this up on localhost I still see the issue so I am not convinced it is purely backend. I have added vite.config.ts to the post to see if that can help and I will creating a minimal-reproducible-example.

Your local server is the "backend" in this case, and the underlying principle is the same regarding what is returned to the frontend client, e.g. the browser. I look forward to the MCVE.

When preparing the MCVE I found it was indeed an issue with my own setup.

I figure it out. It was indeed a mistake in my code. I had a link as BASE_URL/page2/ when it should have been BASE_URL/page2. i.e. the trailing / should not have been there.
